# Interesting simple property of concave function: the directional derivative must be positive only on some convex sets?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, vectors, convex-analysis

Hi let $f$ be a concave function on $\mathbb R^n$. $x_1,x_2,y$ are points in $\mathbb R^n$.

Given that for all $i\in\{1,2\}$:

$(y-x_i)\cdot\nabla f(x_i)\geq 0$ . That is the directional derivative is given to be positive. The direction vector is $\vec{x_iy}$.

Let $z=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$. $z$ is the mid point of $x_1,x_2$.

**Is it true that $(y-z)\cdot\nabla f(z)\geq 0$?**

---

I thought it is false but I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: The directional derivative at a point $x$ in the direction $y$ is $\nabla f(x) \cdot y$.

Comment: @MartinR In this question $y$ is a point and the direction vector is $(y-x_i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If $\ f(s,t)=-s^2-t^2\ $, then $\ f\ $ is a concave function.  If
\begin{align}
 x_1&=(1,1)\\
x_2&=(-1,1)\\
y&=\left(0,\frac{3}{2}\right)
\end{align}
what are
\begin{align}
(y-x_1)&\cdot\nabla f(x_1)\\
(y-x_2)&\cdot\nabla f(x_2)\ \ \text{ and}\\
(y-z)&\cdot\nabla f(z)\ ?
\end{align}

Comment: Hi Ionza you are definitely correct. I'll check some similar cases. I actually made a typo. The question will be interesting if consider convex rather than concave functions. I'll make another question. Thanks again!